# How can I refresh the page When I make changes locally on my wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, visual-studio-code, wordpress-theming, local

I am using local by flywheel, Vscode on Linux and I'm creating a wordpress theme.

I want the page I'm currently working on to auto refresh when I save the page.

e.g. if I'm working on a-page.php

and I add `<h1> new content </h1>` , I don't want to have to click the refresh button on chrome, instead I want it to auto refresh with a save.

How can I refresh the page When I make changes locally on my wordpress theme?

I've looked for flywheel plugins but don't see any.